# How do I open a DTSX file in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019

How do I open a DTSX file for editing using Visual Studio 2019?

I have generated a DTSX file by using the Import Data wizard found in SQL Server Management Studio, using the [same process outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307238/edit-a-dtsx-through-ssms). The [answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54315589/645511) explains how to edit a .dtsx file, but it does not appear to be correct anymore. I am using Visual Studio 2019. The answer says I need to use this link to download SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio:

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

But at that link, it says:

> **Changes in SSDT for Visual Studio 2019**
>
> With Visual Studio 2019, the required functionality to enable Analysis Services, 
>   Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects has moved into the
>   respective Visual Studio extensions. The core SSDT functionality to
>   create Database Projects has remained integral to Visual Studio (you
>   need to select the Data storage, and processing workload during
>   install). There's no more standalone SSDT installation required.
>
> If you already have a license to Visual Studio 2019:
>
> - For SQL Database Projects, install the Data storage and Processing
>     workload for Visual Studio
> - For Analysis Services, Integration Services
>     or Reporting Services projects, install the appropriate extension(s)
>     from the marketplace

I believe I need Integration Services, but it doesn't have a link to the appropriate extension in the marketplace. Through various googling paths<sup>1</sup>, everything keeps pointing back to the [SQL Server Integration Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) extension. I have installed this extension<sup>2</sup>, but I am still unable to open DSTX files.

Here's how I'm attempting to do it: In Visual Studio, am going to File|Open Project. Then I browse to the folder with the .dtsx file in it, change the filter to `*.*` (because .dtsx isn't in the list of supported project extensions), choose the file, and click Open. I get this message box:

[image]

So, my question again: How do I open a DSTX file from Visual Studio 2019?

See below for detailed versions and installed extensions.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, see [Lesson 1-1: Create a new Integration Services project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-1-creating-a-new-integration-services-project?view=sql-server-2017), where they create a DSTX project. The lesson's [Prerequistes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017#prerequisites) instructs you to install the SQL Server Data Tools from [Download SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017), which is the same link from above.

<sup>2</sup> I note that version 3.1 of the extension is currently labeled a Preview and that release notes for this version includes the text, "This is the second preview release. We do not recommend using it for production." But I do not see where I am able to download an earlier version of this extension, either from the marketplace website or from in Visual Studio. I would try the latest production release if I could find it, but it doesn't seem to be available.

I also see there are two notes about issues with this preview release. Neither seem relevant to my situation. The first is a regression in VS 16.2 where they recommend upgrading to 16.2.3. I am already on 16.2.4. The second is an issue where the extension and/or Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019 might be deleted during a VS instance upgrade. I have not done any upgrades to VS since installing this extension.

**Installed Software**

- Visual Studio 2019, version 16.2.4
- SQL Server Management Studio, version 17.9.1.

In Visual Studio, when I go to Help|About Microsoft Visual Studio, I also see the following listed in Installed Products (this list is not complete; it includes only the items that seemed relevant):

- SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.61906.28070
- SQL Server Integration Services   15.0.1301.433

In Visual Studio, when I go to Extensions|Manage Extensions, I see SQL Server Integration Services Projects in the list of installed extensions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message indicates you are trying to open a project/solution.  DTSX is a package.

You first need to open the .sln or .proj file.  Within the project (solution explorer) you can open the dtsx.  Do not try to open the dtsx file from the source control explorer as that does not open with the project references.

In summary, open the solution/project, then open the package from the solution explorer.

Comment: Aha! The file name definitely should have tipped me off, but apparently it's one of those days. Thank you so much for your help; I've spent enough time on it to...well, to compile that much detail in a question, for example.

Comment: You may have to also install SQL Server Integration Services Projects: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview

Comment: What do to when I have dtsx file only? How to debug it? Basically how to make solution or project from dtsx file?

Comment: Create a new project, then add your dtsx file to it.

Answer (score 5):

To edit and create integration services packages (`.dtsx`) is necessary to install [SQL Server Integration Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects).
After installation Visual Studio 2019 can create or edit integration packages either independently (open file) or in *Integration Services Project*. It is also possible to open packages on SQL server even when SSMS fails with message:

```
Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "xxxx" failed with the following error: "Access is denied."
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error message? What causes it, and why is it possible to open the package if you get an "Access is denied" message?

Comment: @KatieKilian I celebrate not getting error message in *Visual Studio* while still getting it in *SSMS*. I'll consider reformulating the answer. I was probably too happy of success when writting it( :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

You need to install SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) and then, in a new project, select integration, and then make a new project and your `.dtsx` file will open. Let me know if this helps and if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install SSMS, SSAS from VS Extensions> (In VS Menu, click "Extensions" and then "Manage Extensions

Comment: The specific name for the extension for VS 2019 is "SQL Server Integration Services Project" and is from Microsoft. When you find the extension and click the [Download] button, you will download an executable.